# How to create popup form properly in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and I'm building a login and register feature for my website. I want the user to click the login or register button and then the form will popup for user to enter their information. The first thing comes to my mind is using modal in bootstrap but I cannot enter anything in the input fields. Does it the right way to do a popup form in React?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use react-modal(https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal) and redux-form(https://redux-form.com/8.3.0/) for this kind of works